# A tab show the same data as the other one in MVC project

Tags: javascript, c#, html, jquery, model-view-controller

I do not understand why I have two tabs that are displaying the same data.  The columns headers appear as they should, so it is the rest of the page, but the data is the same on both tabs.
One thing I noticed is that as of now the data displaying is that of the fifth tab(called Knowledge) and if I flip their order on the index page then the data showing in both tabs is the other one(fourth tab; called Tasks).
The page and the code is about the same on both tabs, the only thing really changing is the data. I have been working on this for hours but I do not seem to find a solution. Code below, I know it is a lot of code but I included everything so you know exactly what I did.
Thank you so much.

**INDEX PAGE**

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#fourthTab">IT Tasks</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#fifthTab">Knowledge</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="fourthTab" class="tab-pane fade in">@Html.Action("ViewAllTasks")</div>
    <div id="fifthTab" class="tab-pane fade in">@Html.Action("ViewAllKnowledgeRealOne")</div>    
</div>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
//-------------------------IT TASKS--------------------------------------------------------------------
        public ActionResult ViewAllTasks()
        {
            HelpDeskDBHandle dbhandle = new HelpDeskDBHandle();
            return View(dbhandle.GetITTasksList());
        }


        //LIST IT TASKS
        public JsonResult ListITTasks()
        {
            HelpDeskDBHandle hdDB = new HelpDeskDBHandle();
            return Json(hdDB.GetITTasksList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }


//*******GET TASKS DETAILS*******************
         public List<ITTasksModel> GetITTasksList()
        {
            connection();
            List<ITTasksModel> Ittaskslist = new List<ITTasksModel>();

            string constring =                               ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HelpDeskSupportConn"].ToString();
            string query = "SELECT * FROM ITTasks";
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (sdr.Read())
                        {
                            Ittaskslist.Add(new ITTasksModel
                            {
                                ITNumber = Convert.ToInt32(sdr["ITNumber"]),
                                ITDescription = Convert.ToString(sdr["ITDescription"]),
                                ITEnterDate = Convert.ToString(sdr["ITEnterDate"]),
                                ITAssignedTo = Convert.ToString(sdr["ITAssignedTo"]),
                                ITEstimatedCompletion = Convert.ToString(sdr["ITEstimatedCompletion"]),
                                ITPriority = Convert.ToString(sdr["ITPriority"]),
                                ITFrom = Convert.ToString(sdr["ITFrom"]),
                                ITStatus = Convert.ToString(sdr["ITStatus"])
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    con.Close();
                }
                return Ittaskslist;
            }
        }


 //-------------------------KNOWLEDGE------------------------------------------------------------------
        //VIEW ALL KNOWLEDGE
        public ActionResult ViewAllKnowledgeRealOne()
        {
            HelpDeskDBHandle dbhandle = new HelpDeskDBHandle();
            return View(dbhandle.GetKnowledgeList());
        }


        //LIST KNOWLEDGE
        public JsonResult ListKnowledgeRealOne()
        {
            HelpDeskDBHandle hdDB = new HelpDeskDBHandle();
            return Json(hdDB.GetKnowledgeList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }


// **********GET KNOWLEDGE DETAILS********
        public List<KnowledgeRealOneModel> GetKnowledgeList()
        {
            connection();
            List<KnowledgeRealOneModel> KnowledgeRealOneList = new List<KnowledgeRealOneModel>();

            string constring =                                 ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HelpDeskSupportConn"].ToString();
            string query = "SELECT * FROM KnowledgeRealOne";
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (sdr.Read())
                        {
                            KnowledgeRealOneList.Add(new KnowledgeRealOneModel
                            {
                                Number = Convert.ToInt32(sdr["Number"]),
                                Subject = Convert.ToString(sdr["Subject"]),
                                //ITEnterDate = Convert.ToDateTime(sdr["ITEnterDate"]),
                                From = Convert.ToString(sdr["From"]),
                                DateCreated = Convert.ToString(sdr["DateCreated"]),
                                AssignedDate = Convert.ToString(sdr["AssignedDate"]),
                                RequestType = Convert.ToString(sdr["RequestType"]),
                                Body = Convert.ToString(sdr["Body"]),
                                DateSubmitted = Convert.ToString(sdr["DateSubmitted"]),
                                Category = Convert.ToString(sdr["Category"])
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    con.Close();
                }
                return KnowledgeRealOneList;
            }
        }
```

**KNOWLEDGE VIEW**

```
@*--------------KNOWLEDGE VIEW----------------------------------------------------------*@

@model IEnumerable<HelpDeskSupport.Models.KnowledgeRealOneModel>

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Knowledge</title>

    <script src="~/Scripts/KnowledgeRealOneJS.js"></script>
</head>

<div class="container">
    <h2>Knowledge</h2>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalKnowledge"          onclick="clearTextBox();">Add New Knowledge</button><br /><br />

    <table class="display table table-striped table-bordered" id="knowledgeRealOneTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Number)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Subject)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.From)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DateCreated)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AssignedDate)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RequestType)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Body)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DateSubmitted)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Category)
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody class="tbody">
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Number)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Subject)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.From)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateCreated)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AssignedDate)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RequestType)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Body)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateSubmitted)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category)
                </td>
            </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**TASKS VIEW**

```
@*TASKS VIEW--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*@


@model IEnumerable<HelpDeskSupport.Models.ITTasksModel>

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>ViewAllTasks</title>

    <script src="~/Scripts/ITTasksJS.js"></script>
</head>

<div class="container">
    <h2>IT Tasks</h2>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"       onclick="clearTextBox();">Add New Task</button><br /><br />

    <table class="display table table-striped table-bordered" id="knowledgeTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ITNumber)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ITDescription)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ITEnterDate)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ITAssignedTo)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ITEstimatedCompletion)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ITPriority)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ITFrom)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ITStatus)
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody class="tbody">
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ITNumber)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ITDescription)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ITEnterDate)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ITAssignedTo)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ITEstimatedCompletion)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ITPriority)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ITFrom)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ITStatus)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**KNOWLEDGE JAVASCRIPT**

```
jQuery(function () {
    loadDataKnowledge();
});

//Load Data function
function loadDataKnowledge() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Tickets/ListKnowledgeRealOne",
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            var html = '';
            $.each(result, function (key, item) {
                html += '<tr>';
                html += '<td>' + item.Number + '</td>';
                html += '<td>' + item.Subject + '</td>';
                html += '<td>' + item.From + '</td>';
                html += '<td>' + item.DateCreated + '</td>';
                html += '<td>' + item.AssignedDate + '</td>';
                html += '<td>' + item.RequestType + '</td>';
                html += '<td>' + item.Body + '</td>';
                html += '<td>' + item.DateSubmitted + '</td>';
                html += '<td>' + item.Category + '</td>';
                html += '<td><a href="#" onclick="return getbyNumber(' + item.Number + ')">Edit</a> |                   <a href="#" onclick="DeleteKnowledge(' + item.Number + ')">Delete</a></td>';
                html += '</tr>';
            });
            $('.tbody').html(html);
            alert("Successful load KNOWLEDGE");
        },
        error: function (errormessage) {
            alert(errormessage.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

**TASKS JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    loadData();
});

//Load Data function
function loadData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Tickets/ListITTasks",
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            var html = '';
            $.each(result, function (key, item) {
                html += '<tr>';
                html += '<td>' + item.ITNumber + '</td>';
                html += '<td>' + item.ITDescription + '</td>';
                html += '<td>' + item.ITEnterDate + '</td>';
                html += '<td>' + item.ITAssignedTo + '</td>';
                html += '<td>' + item.ITEstimatedCompletion + '</td>';
                html += '<td>' + item.ITPriority + '</td>';
                html += '<td>' + item.ITFrom + '</td>';
                html += '<td>' + item.ITStatus + '</td>';
                html += '<td><a href="#" onclick="return getbyTicketNumber(' + item.ITNumber +             ')">Edit</a> | <a href="#" onclick="DeleteItTask(' + item.ITNumber + ')">Delete</a></td>';
                html += '</tr>';
            });
            $('.tbody').html(html);
            alert("Successful Load TASK");
        },
        error: function (errormessage) {
            alert(errormessage.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

THANKS A LOT AGAIN!

Comment: you have `alert()` in your javascript. Does it get triggered? What happens when you change tabs? Are the alerts firing? The behavior you mentioned (flipping the order - only first tab works) points to data retrieval not getting triggered for the 2nd tab.

Comment: Hi, both alerts get triggered when the Index tab first opens, but the data is from only either Knowledge or Task, depending on the order I have them in the Index(data from last one listed gets used for both tabs). When I change tabs the data stays the same, it remains what was first loaded.  The tab (either of the two) gets loaded with its own button and even the columns headers but the data in it is that of the other tab.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your replies. I solved the problem by creating a link to the page and taking it off the navigation bar where all the tabs are